Baking Heightmap, Curved Instead of Flat?


I am trying to bake a heightmap using Map Range. The mesh is -30m to 230m and is shrunk to 0 to 1 values.
I open the heightmap and it is curved instead of flat.
I've tried the other settings of Map Range and linear, stepped linear, etc outputs a curved surface.
I want to achieve an inclined plane not a curved one.

How do you bake the heightmap? What format is it? Are the greyscales linear or some other interpolation or colorspace?

That's a beautiful visualization of the sRGB gamma curve.

Set View Transform in Color Management in Render properties to Raw and the rest to default or depending on the Blender version untick Save as Render or set Color Management settings to raw when using Save As....

For anyone reading that needs clarification. Go to Render Properties and in Color Management change to None.

There is no None for Display Device in the newer versions of Blender.
